# Allow moving multiple items at once between saved lists

Tags: feature-request, saves

### Managing List of Saved Questions

I believe it would be quite a good improvement if one could batch select the Saved items/questions in order to move them all at once between lists more easily.

Comment: [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js)

Comment: Yes, it could be mitigation for not being able to change the default list (*"For later"*).